# IE6 - too much spacing appearing above h3, how do I get rid of it?

Tags: css, xhtml

Example: http://bit.ly/dfjvmT

If you take a look at that URL, you will see an `<h3>` labeled "Send Us Your Resume". Problem is -- in IE6, it has too much space at the top. It's supposed to be margin-top of 16px, but in IE6, it appears more like 24-30px.

I have a reset.css file which has zeroed all margins and paddings, so it's not that.

Just checked, both CSS and XHTML are valid.

And I notice this spacing error only appears when I put a `<div>` before this `<h3>`. Currently, I have `<div class="top"></div>` which appears before this `<h3>`. That part takes care of rounded corners for the container. When I remove that `<div>`, the spacing finally matches in both IE6 and Firefox.

Of course, I need to use that `<div>` for rounded corners. So I'm wondering, what exactly is causing this problem, and is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

**Edit:** Solution found. I had to add `overflow:hidden` to the css of the `<div>` with rounded corners.

Comment: You should use the Developer toolbar to investigate where that additional margin comes from. Guessing is fine but usually doesn't lead to solved problems.

Comment: I just previewed this page on IE6 - everything looks fine. What IE6 are you using? Is it clear IE6, or MultipleIE instance etc?

Comment: Easy fix: don't use IE6.

Comment: Conditional CSS and move on.  Not worth trying to get the same CSS working for every browser including 6 if you can just throw in a little conditional css and be done with it.

Comment: The link in this question is now broken, which breaks the entire context of your question. I'm closing this now as too localized. If you're able to fix it, flag your question for our attention and we'll open it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all right here:

```
#send-resume .top, #send-resume .bottom {
    background: url('../_images/bg-form-top.gif') no-repeat;
    width: 351px;
    height: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Most old browsers incorporate the font-height into the 'automated' height. The font-height by default is like 12 px so the height of the division will automatically be at least 12px high, or whatever your default font-height is for the page. Try setting `font-size: 1px;` in your class and see if it gets rid of your height problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I never use `<br>`. 

I just found the solution. It was to add `overflow: hidden` into the `<div>` that appeared before `<h3>`.

Comment: @animuson Looking at the web page answers all your questions...

Comment: @Jer: The website was not there before, but yeah it's easier to figure out now that I can look at the CSS.

Comment: @codemonkey613: That is an odd solution that theoretically would work.

Answer (score 0):

IE6 doubles the margin on floated elements. 
you can fix this by using an IE6 specific CSS

```
<!--[if IE 6]><link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
```

and make the margin-top exactly half (so 8px) of the value in your original CSS.

Comment: I’m pretty sure it only does that to left/right margins — left if the element was floated left, right if the element was floated right.